# how to add(and install) java openjdk repository to your yum fedora?

Tags: yum

executing this command - yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk

yields - No package java-1.7.0-openjdk available.

That's because i don't have the repo - but im a little clueless as to where, and how to add the repo so that my yum can install it properly.

EDIT:

My Fedora version is:

Linux cl-t046-230cl.privatedns.com 2.6.23.15-80.fc7 #1 SMP Sun Feb 10 17:29:10 EST 2008 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Fedora release 7 (Moonshine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say which version of Fedora you're using, which is a crucial piece of information.

For Fedora 16, this is in the updates repo, so the command above should work fine; that suggests, though doesn't prove, that you're on an earlier version of Fedora.

I've looked in the updates repo for F15 ([at my local mirror](http://ftp.linux.org.uk/pub/distributions/fedora/linux/updates/15/i386/)) and that only has java-1.6.0-openjdk.  So it looks like 1.7.0 didn't come out soon enough for F15 to benefit from it (indeed, there was some discussion in the run-up to F16 about whether or how to get 1.7.0 into that release, you can read it [in this thread](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-August/155277.html) if you want to).

So I definitely don't expect to find 1.7.0 in F14 and earlier, since those versions are now out-of-support.

If you're F15,  you might be able to benefit from a custom build in someone else's repo, but you'll have to to let us know what version of Fedora you're on.  F14 and earlier, I fear you're simply out of luck - and you need to upgrade anyway.

**Edit:** You're using Fedora 7.  Now I can't say for sure that noone's keeping up-to-date packages for F7 in some odd repository somewhere, but it seems **extremely unlikely** to me.

May I repeat my warning that F7 is *wildly* out of date, and not suitable for deploying *anything* on in 2012?  You can't easily upgrade it now (because modern Fedora won't upgrade anything more than two revs out of date, so you'll have to go 7-9-11-13-15-16); if you decide to stay on Fedora, you need to be resigned to upgrades at least once a year.  Failing that, use a server-class OS - CentOS will be most suitable for you, being a Fedora user, but Ubuntu/Debian/SuSE/etc. all have their long-term support offerings too.  Good luck.

Comment: i apologize i missed posting my Fedora version - i updated my post to show which version im running in my system. Is it possible to find a repo source to install openJDK for my current version? Thanks.

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 3):

You may have chosen incorrect package version. You can check for package availability using:

```
$ yum search openjdk
```

If you find the needed package, you can then install it.

Comment: thanks for the tip - so I got a no matches found for this.